# Waking up a killed app using didEnterRegion and then scanning for peripherals using scanForPeripheralsWithServices

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

I know that the common way to use iBeacons even if the app was killed is to use Monitoring (for example, monitor a region defined by a UUID) and when `didEnterRegion` is called start Ranging for iBeacons (to fetch each beacon's major and minor).

Did anyone tried running a Corebluetooth `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` instead of Ranging?
This won't give the major & minor - iOS hides the iBeacon identifiers (uuid, major & minor) from the Corebluetooth API.
However, it can give other information that the non-standard iBeacon advertises (or other BLE peripherals around), and may even let you connect to them (in the 5-seconds "wakeup").

Thanks

Comment: Did you make it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you say is absolutely possible.  As you point out, since you cannot access the beacon identifiers, you will not know which peripheral in the callback from `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` is the beacon that triggered the region entry event.  But you can certainly scan for these devices for a brief time after your app is launched into the background by this event.